# Generate List with Every Combination between two variables

Tags: c#, arrays, list

How can I auto generate a `List<string>` with every combination between `A00B00` to `A100B100`?

I think it would be 10,100 items.

So the List would contain:

```
A00B00
A00B01
A00B02
...
A01B00
A01B01
A01B02
...
A100B98
A100B99
A100B100
```

It needs to keep the `AxxBxx` format. I do not want it to be scrambled like `0A01B0`.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Dan All I know of is how to make an empty list with `Enumerable.Range(0,100)`.

Comment: `for (int i = 0 i < 101; i++){for (int j = 0; j < 101; j++){yourList.Add(string.Format("A{0:00}B{1:00}", i, j));}}`

Comment: so it's all between 0 and 100?

Comment: @StephenMuecke It looks to be working, thanks. http://rextester.com/QMR26498

Answer (score 1):

Since you have a range of `0-100` and you just have `A` and `B` as a prefix, We populate two lists each with `ints` from `0 to 100` and then use `System.Linq` to find all combinations and append then to a `list` with a delimiter. Now just replace the delimiter.

There are a bunch of ways you can go about it, I would recommend using `System.Linq`

```
public static IEnumerable<string> FindAllCombinationsAnotherWay()
{
    List<int> ListOne = Enumerable.Range(1, 100).ToList();
    List<int> ListTwo = Enumerable.Range(1, 100).ToList();

    var result = ListOne.SelectMany((a, indexA) =>
             ListTwo.Where((b, indexB) =>
                    ListTwo.Contains(a) ? !b.Equals(a) && indexB > indexA
                                      : !b.Equals(a))
                  .Select(b => string.Format("A{0:00}B{1:00}", a, b)));

    return result.Distinct();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that easily:

```
var result = new List<string>();
foreach (var i in Enumerable.Range(0, 101))
{
    foreach (var j in Enumerable.Range(0, 101))
    {
        result.Add($"A{i:00}B{j:00}");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Such combinations are called [Cartesian products](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product), here's another LINQ solution:

```
var lst = Enumerable.Range(0, 101)
                  .SelectMany(a => Enumerable.Range(0, 101).Select(b => $"A{a:00}B{b:00}"))
                  .ToList();
```