# Check if String Contains Match in Enumerable.Range Filter List

Tags: c#, arrays, list

I want to check if a string contains a word or number from a list and remove it from the string.

I want to use `Enumerable.Range()` to create the filter list and use it to filter many different strings.

I'm trying to combine two previous answers:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/49733139/6806643
https://stackoverflow.com/a/49740832/6806643

---

**The sentence I want to filter:**

> This is a A05B09 hello 02 100 test

---

**Filter**

`A00B00-A100B100`, `01-100`, `000-100`, `hello`

Should read:

> This is a test

---

**Old Way**
`For Loop` - Works
http://rextester.com/BJL70824

**New Way**
`Enumerable Range List` - Does not work
http://rextester.com/ZSCM64375

---

**C#**

```
List<List<string>> filters = Enumerable.Range(0, 101)
       .SelectMany(a => Enumerable.Range(0, 101).Select(b => "A{0:00}B{1:00}"))
       .Select(i => Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select(c => string.Empty).ToList())
           .SelectMany(a => Enumerable.Range(0, 101).Select(b => "{0:000}"))
           .SelectMany(a => Enumerable.Range(0, 101).Select(b => "{0:00}"))
           .SelectMany(a => Enumerable.Range(0, 1).Select(b => "hello"))
           .ToList();

List<string> matches = new List<string>();

// Sentence
string sentence = "This is a A05B09 hello 02 100 test";
string newSentence = string.Empty;


// Find Matches
for (int i = 0; i < filters.Count; i++)
{
    // Add to Matches List
    if (sentence.Contains(filters[i].ToString()))
    {
        matches.Add(filters[i]);
    }
}

// Filter Sentence
newSentence = Regex.Replace(
    sentence
,   @"(?<!\S)(" + string.Join("|", matches) + @")(?!\S)"
,   ""
,   RegexOptions.IgnoreCase
);

// Display New Sentence
Console.WriteLine(newSentence);
```

Comment: well, you aren't using b in your selects...

Comment: @KeithNicholas Here is a simplified version. http://rextester.com/RHU90893

Comment: I think the way you instantiate `filters` is not right. I'm getting a lot of "hello" there. Also, that is a `List<string>`, and not a list of lists. Even you rextester link fails due to this error. Also, `"A{0:00}B{1:00}"` is exactly that string thousand of times, you should be using `a` and `b` and the `$` symbol. Anyway, I think it doesn't make sense to create all possible combinations. If you want to filter `A###B###C###`, are you going to create a 1 billion items list? That doesn't make sense at all.

Comment: your linked code doesn't match the question code, in your linked code you use b in the selects

Comment: @KeithNicholas That's what the original answer used. I'm not sure which to use or how to use it correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think creating a list of all possible combinations is a very bad approach. You are creating huge lists which will make your process use a lot of RAM and be very slow without any good reason. Why not just create a good Regex? For example, with this expression, you get your desired string:

```
\b(A\d\dB\d\d|A100B100|0?\d\d|100|hello)\b\s*
```

That is assuming you don't want to replace stuff like `A101B101` or `123`.

If you want to replace those as well, the regex is a bit simpler:

```
\b(A\d\d\d?B\d\d\d?|\d\d\d?|hello)\b\s*
```

Comment: If I want to replace `A101B101` and further, would I just change it to `A999B999`? And for `123` change the regex to `|1000|` to cover a larger range?

Comment: I guess you need to learn regular expressions first. I added the regex if you want to include those as well. `\d` are digits 0-9 and `?` makes the previous token optional. those `\b` are word separators, `\s` a space character and `*` is a quantifier "0 or more".

Comment: Part of the problem was your "I want to use Enumerable.Range()". Why was that? If you had simply explained what you needed, all this SelectMany nightmware would have never existed. :P

Comment: I wasn't sure how else to do it. I thought using Enumerable.Range() to create a large filter list.

Comment: Imagine you needed to remove any 6-letter word. Would you create a list with 387420489 items?

Comment: I had originally planned it to be for a 10,000 item filter, but I was trying to avoid it getting too big if I had to add more.

Answer (score 1):

Your this line seems not meet your requirements.`.SelectMany(a => Enumerable.Range(0, 101).Select(b => "A{0:00}B{1:00}"))`

Can you try this Linq?

```
List<string> filters = Enumerable.Range(0, 101)
                                 .SelectMany(a => Enumerable.Range(0, 101).Select(b => $"A{a:00}B{b:00}"))
                                 .Union(Enumerable.Range(0, 101).Select(b => $"{b:000}"))
                                 .Union(Enumerable.Range(0, 101).Select(b => $"{b:00}"))
                                 .Union(new List<string> {"hello"})
                                 .ToList();
```

This verion can give you expected result on rextester

```
List<string> filters = Enumerable.Range(0, 101)
                                 .SelectMany(a => Enumerable.Range(0, 101).Select(b => string.Format("A{0:00}B{1:00}", a, b)))
                                 .Union(Enumerable.Range(0, 101).Select(b => string.Format("{0:000}", b)))
                                 .Union(Enumerable.Range(0, 101).Select(b => string.Format("{0:00}", b)))
                                 .Union(new List<string> { "hello" })
                                 .ToList();
```

Comment: It filtered out `hello` but not `A05B09`, `02`, `100`. http://rextester.com/YQY59927

Comment: I run this code in Visual Studio and It is work. In rextester not support $ notation, hence it gives filter list like that (A00B00, A00B00 .....A00B00)

Comment: If you don't support string interpolation (`$`), you must use `string.Format`. For example: `string.Format("A{0:00}B{1:00}", a, b)`. But again, I highly discourage this brute-force approach.

Comment: This worked well. Take a look at Andrew's answer, it has been simplified into one line with regex.

Comment: I do not know your requirement. Hence, I do not change your code structure, I only found and fix whats your missing. If @Andrew's solution can be applied in your code, it is better solution. I also recommend it :)